# Unable to make public long com.sun.management.internal.OperatingSystemImpl.getOpenFileDescriptorCount()

Tags: java, maven, java-11

I am getting the below error in server log in Java 11. Is there any solution for it?

```
[2019-05-02 18:06:18 IST] [] ERROR com.codahale.metrics.ScheduledReporter [SID= UID= BGCD=] - Exception thrown from Slf4jReporter#report. Exception was suppressed.
java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make public long com.sun.management.internal.OperatingSystemImpl.getOpenFileDescriptorCount() accessible: module jdk.management does not "opens com.sun.management.internal" to unnamed module @489448ac
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:340)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:280)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.checkCanSetAccessible(Method.java:198)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.setAccessible(Method.java:192)
    at deployment.myPage.war//com.codahale.metrics.jvm.FileDescriptorRatioGauge.invoke(FileDescriptorRatioGauge.java:48)
    at deployment.myPage.war//com.codahale.metrics.jvm.FileDescriptorRatioGauge.getRatio(FileDescriptorRatioGauge.java:35)
    at deployment.myPage.war//com.codahale.metrics.RatioGauge.getValue(RatioGauge.java:64)
    at deployment.myPage.war//com.codahale.metrics.RatioGauge.getValue(RatioGauge.java:11)
    at deployment.myPage.war//com.codahale.metrics.DerivativeGauge.getValue(DerivativeGauge.java:23)
    at deployment.myPage.war//com.codahale.metrics.Slf4jReporter.logGauge(Slf4jReporter.java:306)
    at deployment.myPage.war//com.codahale.metrics.Slf4jReporter.report(Slf4jReporter.java:220)
    at deployment.myPage.war//com.codahale.metrics.ScheduledReporter.report(ScheduledReporter.java:243)
    at deployment.myPage.war//com.codahale.metrics.ScheduledReporter$1.run(ScheduledReporter.java:182)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
```

Answer (score 12):

One of the dependencies of your project is trying to access a jvm api which was moved to an internal java module, and is no longer exposed.

Running the application with following flag should solve the problem:

```
--add-opens jdk.management/com.sun.management.internal=ALL-UNNAMED
```

Comment: This works perfectly. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

This issue was fixed in Dropwizard metrics 4.0.0, see
[https://github.com/dropwizard/metrics/pull/1236](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/14183)

So you need to raise the version of your dependency.
In case you are using Spring Boot, you can raise the parent version to 2.1.

If raising the version is not an option, follow @senjin.hajrulahovic's answer to open `com.sun.management.internal` module.